# How can I disable "add application for mailto links" bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, webmail, mailto, protocol-handler

Every time I log on to my webmail I see a bar like on image below. I don't want to add this as an application and it is pretty annoying to close this every time. How can I disable it permanently?

The bar says this:
[image: example]

**EDIT:**
I tried to use Firebug to see what causes this bar to appear but with no luck. Anyone help?

**EDIT 2:**

Su's answer from http://webmasters.stackexchange.com :

> This is done by registering a protocol handler. From that page:
>
> navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto",
>                                     "https://www.example.com/?uri=%s",
>                                     "Example Mail");
>
> The site would just have to run a similar snippet at an appropriate
>   moment(login, in your case).

Link: [registering a protocol handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Web-based_protocol_handlers#Registering)

How can this be blocked?

Comment: That sounds like something coming from your webmail. Have you tried looking in your webmail settings to see if you can disable it?

Comment: I know that my webmail might send something to Firefox in order to display this. I want make Firefox ignore this.

Comment: I'm not having much luck figuring out how the webpage might request it. If you can find out, you might be able to block it using something like Ad-Block Plus.

Comment: you could probably also write a Greasemonkey userscript that selectively overrides whatever Javascript functionality on the page that is trying to register itself as a mailto handler..

Comment: As some Firefox settings [are OS-dependent](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.protocol-handler.expose.%28protocol%29), the answer may depend on your OS too. So can you specify your operating system and the Firefox version.

Answer (score 33):

have you tried going to about:config

There are some keys in there relating to mailto:

```
network.protocol-handler.external.mailto;true
network.protocol-handler.expose.mailto;false
network.protocol-handler.warn-external.mailto;false
```

You could try toggling them, I can't test as I can't recreate whats happening for you, I think maybe the first of the three to false maybe a good start,

Be careful when editing this config as it may cause strange things to happen maybe even break firefox.

Comment: This recently just happened to me, after over 15 years of using it. Changing `network.protocol-handler.external.mailto` to false seems to have worked for me.

Comment: This did the trick for outlook365 and FF 89.

Comment: Only setting the `network.protocol-handler.external.mailto` preference to `false` was needed in Firefox 94 (Tutanota webmail, Linux).

Comment: yep, network.protocol-handler.external.mailto:false worked for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Add "outlook.live.com" as an application for mailto links?]

It insists on being added, right? So try the following.

- Add it.
- Go to Firefox Settings / General / Applications.
- You will see that next to `mailto` there is a combo box of options to handle `mailto` links. That which you just added is in the list of options. Most probably it is the selected option.
- Just choose another one; the one which was selected before the first step.

As a result

- the message will never appear again (since you clicked <kbd>Add application</kbd> in the first step),
- Firefox will operate as before (since in the last step you chose the `mailto` app, which was in use before the first step).

Definitely the message should contain a "Don't ask me again" option, which is a bug in Firefox, as [Danny Garside pointed out](https://superuser.com/a/1680198/1197081).

Comment: In my case (nowadays?) the mailto option was still set to "Always Ask" so this answer boiled down to "Just add it". For some reason I didn't come up with it myself, thanks for the hint ;)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it has been a persistent [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668577) for ~10 years.

There's also a more recently raised [bug with a broader scope that might encompass this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1728275).

The only solution I have found ([[1]](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668577#c42),[[2]](https://superuser.com/questions/363827/how-can-i-disable-add-application-for-mailto-links-bar-in-firefox/370235#comment2418962_370235)) has the unfortunate side-effect of **disabling the operation of all mailto links**.

> 1. open new tab page address: about:config
> 2. find variable: network.protocol-handler.external.mailto
> 3. double-click it to set to false

Answer (score 1):

**Another little bad news, because Mozilla has made another change that's why now it didn't work with Firefox-v70.**

As you can probably guess, apparently the file "**userContent.css**" can't rectify this trouble anymore... And no I wasn't able to find another solution even with the file "**userChrome.css**"
But at least, it could be reactivate :

```
lockPref("toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets",true);
## How to remove the button close on every tabs ?
## Just recopy this example inside the "userChrome.css"
@-moz-document url(chrome://browser/content/browser.xhtml)
{
    .tab-close-button {display:none !important;}
}
```

So thank you @0x7c0 because I had found this solution :

```
lockPref("network.protocol-handler.external.mailto",false);
## At this moment, the notification has vanished on the new website of Tutanota.
## Which can be reach only at this new adress : "https://mail.tutanota.com/login"
## That's right, now the previous adress : "https://app.tutanota.com/#login" doesn't seem to exist (at all).
## I will assume Tutanota has probably made the choice to remove it.
```

PS : For the record and for once [reddit was hepful.](https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/brmi8v/psa_firefox_v69_users_will_have_to_set_a_pref_to/)

Answer (score 0):

> … disable it permanently?

Mozilla bug [668577 - registerProtocolHandler notification should provide a "don't ask me again" button](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668577) draws attention to [How to hide/disable Firefox notification for addon/application | Firefox Support Forum | Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/questions/994658#answer-556629) (2011-06-30))

https://github.com/MrAlex94/Waterfox/issues/680#issuecomment-401004043 gives a (legacy) [Stylish 2.1.1](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/stylish/versions/?page=1#version-2.1.1) workaround that's effective for:

> Add Tutanota

### Add o2 Poczta

For this case, you could try:

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);

/*
Adapted from https://support.mozilla.org/questions/994658#answer-556629 
for https://superuser.com/q/363827/84988
*/

notification[label^="Add o2 Poczta"][value="Protocol Registration: mailto"] {
  display: none !important; 
}
```

Firefox Quantum might require a different approach but the essence of the workaround should be the same; styling.