# How to turn off Outlook asking for it to be application for mailto links?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, office365

Every time I open outlook.office.com in my browser on Windows 10, I get the message:
[image]

I have to close that manually every time. How can I turn that message off permanently?

And no, I don't want outlook.office.com to be my application for `mailto` links.

I am using Firefox 89.0.2 (64-bit).

Comment: IIRC Firefox does not offer an option to permanently decline.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-program-used-open-email-links  does this answer your question ?

Comment: Ah yes: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=668577 // I think it's possible to disable protocol handlers altogether. Is that acceptable for you?

Comment: @1NN I don't want to set or change an email client, I just want to get rid of this pop-up.

Comment: @DanielB I tried the UserChrome.css solution, but it didn't work. According to the description it works on ff 28 and 31; I'm using ff 89.

Answer (score 1):

The comments in https://superuser.com/a/370235/478867 read:

> This recently just happened to me, after over 15 years of using it.
> Changing network.protocol-handler.external.mailto to false seems to
> have worked for me. – Asinine Sep 21 '20 at 21:12

> This did the trick for outlook365 and FF 89. – Alfabravo Jul 7 at 14:01

I am using ff 89 and when I changed `network.protocol-handler.external.mailto` to `false` in `about:config`, the pop-up doesn't come up anymore when I refresh the page.

Comment: The popup doesn't show anymore BUT any association with `mailto` links stops working too!